# Generate Random and Print List on 1 Line

Tags: python, list, random, integer, range

For an assignment, I am trying to write a function named Exam, which takes one argument n where n>2.
The function is supposed to create a list (list1) of n random integers in `range(1,5)` and print all elements of list1 on one line.

So far what I have is :

```
def Exam(n):
    import random
    random.randrange(1,5)
```

I am not sure how to limit the input to n>2 or even really what it means. If anyone can assist or give hint, it would be appreciated!

**Updated code:**

```
def Test(n):
    import random
    random.randrange(1,5)
    list1*[]
    if n>2:
        for i in range (n):
            list1.append(random.randrange(1.5))
```

Does this seem on the right path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def list_n(n):
    if n < 2:
       return False
    list = []
    for x in range(n):
       list.append(random.randrange(1,5))
    return list
```

using list comprehension:

```
def list_n(n):
    if n < 2:
       return False
    return [random.randrange(1,5) for x in range(n)]
```

Comment: sberry used list comprehension, which is a way to slightly shorten above `list = [random.randrange(1,5) for x in range(n)]`